# Is there any way to test Firebase notification XMPP Server?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently developing an application server to send notifications to android app's using the XMPP version of the API. Now I want to simulate sending a lot of messages to see how my application server reacts and how to deal in case the `CONNECTION_DRAINING` error is returned by FCM. Is there any way to send a lot of messages to "fake" devices? I want to stress my application server to send for example 1K, 100K or 1M notifications messages. I know that there is a Testing Enviroment (port 5236) but I don't know which are exactly the differences between it and the Production enviroment.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to send messages to *fake* devices. In order to send a message, you need a target, commonly a `registration_token`, which is generated on the client app. Luckily for Android, even an emulator could generate a registration token.